# Why can't I give any answers anymore?

Tags: support, post-ban

I can add comments but I am not able to give any answers anymore. Why?

Comment: So, you did get "we're no longer accepting answers from this account", right?

Answer (score 6):

You are blocked form answering.

Editing or asking is not the only way and in fact not the best way. Edit your answers to improve them. Two or three upvotes on your answers can already be enough, but if your answers are further downvoted, your chances form recovery are decreased.

Out of the 5 answers, plus probably a few deleted ones, you have not one positively scored answer. That is a very bad thing.

Your answers are generally very short and lack correct use of spelling and grammar, even things you should know: Use of capital letters, punctuation, things like writing dont instead of don't.

Bottom line: Edit your answers to improve them!

Answer (score 4):

This means that you've been blocked from answering questions. This is presumably because you've accumulated enough low-quality answers. The only way to reverse this ban is to contribute positively elsewhere, like editing or asking.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. .. I guess that is the reason... Im a newb though :-)

Comment: And another question right away. .. why the downvote for the question?

Comment: @user18502 Because there is an explaination in the help center and because there are already to many of these questions.

Comment: Lol you guys are awesome! Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: For the record, I told him to go here, as I wasn't certain why. Fortunately, one's Meta-score has very little bearing on anything else...